# any reports, papers about how immutable objects affect jvm heap memory?

Tags: java, scala, memory, immutability

I used to apply Jodatime of which every objects from it is almost immutable in my Android application. And now I'm wonder how immutable objects affect jvm heap memory.
I think immutability is good for multi threading because it makes programmers avoid complex multi threading issues. But it is likely that its heavy use can fill in young generation more often than mutable object which can be shared and reused.
So I'd like to know  if there's any studies or profiling result of how immutable objects affects jvm heap memory especially young generation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: may be more suitable for a chat room

Comment: Immutable object tend to create more garbage, but reuse of mutable objects is more often useful for short lived objects. By the time you get into the survivor spaces it might not make much difference. More immutable object tend to need more Eden space, but escape analysis can help (though I am not sure it does on Android)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think so. I should delve into escape analysis because I don't know it at all :) anyways, there's no data at all about the gc frequencies when many immutable objects are used over codebase? Or researchers don't need to study it because it's so obvious? what do you think so.

Comment: @Jayjay I believe it is highly dependant on what the application does, used rarely immutable have a trivial impact. Over use them and it will limit your performance.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree with you that it's dependent on what type of applications. I can frequently see that normally researchers conduct experiments on several types of application to know some effects.